# JavaScript Regex to replace zeros in date, except in the year

Tags: javascript, regex, date, replace

I need to make a date string of `07-26-2012` look like `7-26-2012`.  Easy right

```
date = date.replace(/^0/, '');
```

But `07-05-2012` also needs to be `7-5-2012`.  What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `date = date.replace( /0(\d-)/g, "$1" );`

Simple Test.

```
var re = /0(\d[\-/])/g;
console.log( "07/02/2012".replace( re, "$1" ) == "7/2/2012" );
console.log( "12-02-2012".replace( re, "$1" ) == "12-2-2012" );
console.log( "01-1-2012".replace( re, "$1" ) == "1-1-2012" );
```

If you're doing heavy date manipulation in javascript then check out [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)